# Resize loaded sprite from a texture with type multiple (width and height not match)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hello I'm having a problem that I don't understand why that is happening, the problem is that:

I have a texture of type multiple where I load all of my cards sprites

texture:
[image: texture image]

as you can see each card has its own Sprite properties that define the limit of the image and on this example, you will see that the width is 402 and height is 563.

but for some reason when I load the sprite using
`Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(sheetName)` and then accessing to the specific sprite for example (`sprites[0]`)

if I do

```
sprites[0].rect.width
sprites[0].rect.height
```

the values returned are different than the values specified before on the image and I need these values to scale the sprite width a specific width and height using this formula

```
 var factorX = (CARD_WIDTH / sprites[0].rect.width );
 var factorY = (CARD_HEIGHT / sprites[0].rect.height ) ;
 transform.localScale = new Vector2(factorX, factorY);
```

because the values for width and height are different the factor that I'm getting is wrong.

also, I just noted that the values that I'm getting are the same that unity editor shows to me here 
[image]

My question is:

why I'm getting different values for width and height?

Answer (score 0):

The two ratios are about the same, could it be showing you the resolution of the thumbnail's mip map rather than the raw texture?  You could try turning off Generate Mipmaps in the texture import settings if it's on